# Android how to programmatically set Button stroke and radius

Tags: android, button, styles

I have this activity with 48 `Button` that the user can touch and change text and background color.

**I have edited the style of the default `Buttons` like this**
[image]

**But when the user change the background color i have this bad result**

[image]

These are the xmls that style the dafault `Buttons`

**buttons.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused"
        android:state_focused="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />

</selector>
```

**button_default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="100dp"
        />
    <solid
        android:color="#FFFFFF"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#787878"
        />
</shape>
```

In the other xml change only the color so i avoid to post them.
And here is the code that change the `Button`programmatically.
I take from `DB` all changed `Button` saved with `ID` and set the color of the `Button`.

```
   //Get all materie inside database
    List<Materia> materia = db.getAllMaterie();
    //change all TextView inputed from user
    if(materia.isEmpty()){
        //do nothing
    }else {
        for (Materia mat : materia) {
            //Change all the Button with values stored inside the database
            int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(mat.getID(), "id", getPackageName());
            final Button changedButton = (Button) findViewById(resId);
            changedButton.setText(mat.getMateria());
            changedButton.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            changedButton.setBackgroundColor(mat.getColor());

        }
    }
```

But i lose the radius and stroke property.
There is some way to set them programmatically?
**Other suggestions are accepted!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with this line of code

```
changedButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(mat.getColor(), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Instead of

```
changedButton.setBackgroundColor(mat.getColor());
```

I get back the background of the my default `Button` with `getBackground()` and after i set the color with `setColorFilter(int, mode);`

So the result become

```
//Get all materie inside database
    List<Materia> materia = db.getAllMaterie();
    //change all TextView inputed from user
    if(materia.isEmpty()){
        //do nothing
    }else {
        for (Materia mat : materia) {
            //Change all the Button with values stored inside the database
            int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(mat.getID(), "id", getPackageName());
            final Button changedButton = (Button) findViewById(resId);
            changedButton.setText(mat.getMateria());
            changedButton.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            changedButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(mat.getColor(), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that you should set the drawable programatically.

```
Drawable buttonDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.buttons.xml);
buttonDrawable.mutate()
changedButton.setBackgroundDrawable(buttonDrawable);
```

Comment: I must create another btn.xml with the property stroke and radius?
btnA is my changedButton?

Comment: why not use existing one?

Comment: above code was just the sample, however i have updated it according to your variable names.

Comment: I can't use the existing one because they have set the color!
In my case i take the color from DB and is not always the same.
Now i try your code! Thanks for the new edit!

Comment: setBackgroundDrawable(buttonDrawable); is deprecated!
Anyway it doesn't work.