# Android GUI issues in the tablet with changedButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, mode);

Tags: android, android-layout

How say in the title, my app work perfectly in the smartphones (Samsung S2 and Samsung S3), but have a GUI bug in the Tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab S with Android 5.0.2).

This activity can be changed by the user.
He can touch one button and change text and color like this

[image]

But in the Tablet if the user switch orientation or close and open the activity, sometimes appear this problem!

[image]

All the `Button`s take the color of the first inputed color!
And if the user swap orientation or close and re-open the `Activity` everything returns to normal state!

Here the code that change all `Button`s that the user has changed in the past!

```
static String clickedButtonViewId;
private List<MaterieVoti> materie;
MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_table);

//Get all materie inside database
     List<Materia> materia = db.getAllMaterie();
     //change all TextView inputed from user
     if(materia.isEmpty()){
         //do nothing
     }else {
         for (Materia mat : materia) {
             //Change all the Button with values stored inside the database
             int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(mat.getID(), "id", getPackageName());
             Button changedButton = (Button) findViewById(resId);
             changedButton.setText(mat.getMateria());
             changedButton.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
             changedButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(mat.getColor(), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

         }
     }
 }

//Take back data from ActivityAddMateria
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
                String result = data.getStringExtra("result"); //Take the materia from Dialog
                int color = data.getIntExtra("color", 1); //Take the color from Dialog

                //Controllo se il Button è già presente nel db se presente aggiorno se non presente inserisco
                boolean modifica = db.Exists(clickedButtonViewId);

                if(!modifica) {

                    //Materia da inserire in un nuovo spazio
                    db.addMateriaToDb(new Materia(clickedButtonViewId, result, color));

                }else{

                    //Materia già presente nel Button quindi aggiorno la materia
                    db.updateMateria(new Materia(clickedButtonViewId, result, color));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Materia modificata!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                //Cambio subito il Button
                int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(clickedButtonViewId, "id", getPackageName());
                final Button clickedtextView = (Button) findViewById(resId);

                clickedtextView.setText(result);
                clickedtextView.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            }

            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Nessuna materia inserita
            }

        }
    }//onActivityResult
```

drawable/buttons.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused"
        android:state_focused="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />

</selector>
```

drawable/button_default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="100dp"
        />
    <solid
        android:color="#FFFFFF"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#787878"
        />
</shape>
```

I found the problem but don't know why it doesn't work.
If i change `changedButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(mat.getColor(), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);` with `changedButton.setBackgroundColor(mat.getColor());` the problem disappear but i lose the button style property!

One way is to create a drawable/button_style_red.xml, drawable/button_style_yellow.xml and with the code `Button.setDrawable(button_style_color);` i can change the `Button`.
**But there is some way to change only the color but not the style of the `Button`s??**

The `Button.getBackground().setColorFilter(mat.getColor(), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);` doesn't work to all device!!

This is my old question for make the changed button with same style [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579087/android-how-to-programmatically-set-button-stroke-and-radius)

Comment: You might want to consider locking the orientation.  I've had this problem with widgets (that don't change on a phone, but do on a tablet).  The entire activity is destroyed and remade when the orientation changes.  So you have to make sure that when the activity recreates, it continues everything about it's previous state.

Comment: It happens if I close and reopen the activity too, not only with screen orientation (i try with `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` but the problem still remaining).
Is the onCreate an onResume()!
As you can see i use myStyle buttons, it can be the problem?
After i use a normal button style and i haven't this problem in the tablet!

Comment: I'm thinking if it is where the app is resuming then yeah.  Only, if it doesn't happen on a phone at all, that IS weird.

Comment: For this reason i don't understand the problem!
The phone work but the tablet not!
But when i use a normal Button style all work fine in the tablet and in the phone too.
When i change the button style in the tablet don't work in the phone yes!
Now i edit the post with the button style!

Comment: I found the problem.
`changedButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(mat.getColor(), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);` instead of `changedButton.setBackgroundColor(mat.getColor());` but don't know why!
This is my old question for make the changed button with same style [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579087/android-how-to-programmatically-set-button-stroke-and-radius)